# PostGress SQL c++ ошибка "Syntax error at or near @" PQexec

Tags: c++, postgresql

```
#include "targetver.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include "libpq-fe.h"
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    const char *conninfo;
    PGconn     *conn;


    std::string EmailToDB = "gfdgfdshj@mail.ru";
    std::string PswdToDb = "1234";

    char d = char(64); //Тестовый Char для передачи чистый ANCII

    const char *paramValues[2] = { (char *)&EmailToDB, (char *)&PswdToDb };


    conninfo = "hostaddr = '192.168.0.130' port = '5433' user = 'postgres' password = 'pass' connect_timeout = '2'";

    conn = PQconnectdb(conninfo);
    PQsetClientEncoding(conn, "UTF-8");

    if (PQstatus(conn) != CONNECTION_OK)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Connection to database failed: %s",
            PQerrorMessage(conn));
        //exit(0);
    }

    else {
        PQsetClientEncoding(conn, "UTF8");
        printf("Good Done \n");


        std::string insert = "CREATE ROLE "+ EmailToDB+" WITH PASSWORD "+PswdToDb; 

        PGresult *res = PQexec(conn, insert.c_str());


        fprintf(stderr, "UserCreeate: %s",
            PQerrorMessage(conn));

        PQfinish(conn);
    }

    system("pause");



    return 0;
}
```

Код не отрабатывает, выплевывает ошибку обозначенную в заголовке.
Не принимает в запрос вообще никакие символы кроме буквенных, цифры в имени пользователя и пароле тоже не принимаются, только a-Z.
Помогите разобраться в чем проблема.

Comment: Выполните ваш запрос руками и получите то же самое. Потому что пароль без кавычек.

Comment: “Syntax error at or near @” PQexec обратите внимание на символ, который не отрабатывается. ТАкже напишите как правильно создавать пароль, только не нужно говорить что пароль не должен содержть №;%:@#$% и прочие символы...бред и билиберда, также поясните каким образом хранить в С++ строковые переменные не используя " ", если считаете что они портят SQL запрос

Comment: Вообще не понял о чём это. Заключите пароль в кавычки *в запросе* (не забыв экранировать кавычки в пароле, если они там есть).

Comment: См. функию PQescapeIdentifier()

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка возникает потому, что пароль не заключён в кавычки. Кроме того, если в нём могут быть не-ASCII символы, его нужно дополнительно обработать. Роль тоже должна быть предварительно обработана. Для этого предназначены функции [PQescapeLiteral()](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/9.5/libpq-exec#LIBPQ-PQESCAPELITERAL) и [PQescapeIdentifier()](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/9.5/libpq-exec#LIBPQ-PQESCAPEIDENTIFIER). Обратите внимание на то, что возвращаемые этими функциями значения нельзя использовать напрямую, их нужно сохранять для последующего освобождения выделенной памяти:

```
const char role[] = "gfdgfdshj@mail.ru";
const char password[] = "%$#$'";
/*
 *
 */
char *escaped_role = PQescapeIdentifier( conn, role, sizeof(role) );
char *escaped_password = PQescapeLiteral( conn, password, sizeof(password) );
std::string insert = "CREATE ROLE ";
insert += escaped_role;
insert += " WITH PASSWORD ";
insert += escaped_password;

PGresult *rc = PQexec( conn, insert.c_str() );
/* 
 *
 */
PQfreemem( escaped_role );
PQfreemem( escaped_password );
```

Comment: Спасибо за более подробный комментарий! Нет ли у Вас в арсенале варианта перевода String в Char, который гарантированно будет работать .c_str() отрабатывает не всегда.

Comment: @lostandleft, что значит "не всегда"? `.c_str()` всегда работает одинаково, стабильно и предсказуемо. Есть ещё метод `.data()`, только непонятно зачем он тут. Кстати, оба они возвращают не `char *`, а `const char *`, это разные вещи...

Comment: Спасибо за пример, тот вариант что я ниже написал не работает с рядом символов, посмотрел Ваш, разобрался, проблем нет, все отлично.

Answer (score -3):

Все ежики вырождены...нужно сам запрос оформить так:

```
std::string insert = "CREATE USER \"" + EmailToDB + "\" WITH PASSWORD "+ "'\"" + PswdToDb + "\"'"; // РАБОТАЕТ
```

Проблем с конструкцией пока что не вижу, буду пробовать грабли